# Ползунок: как сделать выбор половины блока?

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Здравствуйте. Сделал скрипт который отображает количество выбранных кругов.
Но мне нужно сделать, чтобы можно было выбрать пол круга. Подскажите как это возможно?
Можно это сделать так:
В место одной картинки использовать две половинки, но это не легко и мне кажется есть решении проще. 
[Вот скрипт](http://jsfiddle.net/oac2Lw13/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<center>
Вы выбрали: <a id="info">17</a>/20
<div id="heart">
<img id="1" src="http://test.epic-mine.ru/1.png">
<img id="2" src="http://test.epic-mine.ru/1.png">
<img id="3" src="http://test.epic-mine.ru/1.png">
<img id="4" src="http://test.epic-mine.ru/1.png">
<img id="5" src="http://test.epic-mine.ru/1.png">
<img id="6" src="http://test.epic-mine.ru/1.png">
<img id="7" src="http://test.epic-mine.ru/1.png">
<img id="8" src="http://test.epic-mine.ru/1.png">
<img id="9" src="http://test.epic-mine.ru/2.png">
<img id="10" src="http://test.epic-mine.ru/3.png">
</div>
</center>
```

**CSS**:

```
#heart img{
width: 9%;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    img = $("#heart img");
    img.mouseenter(function () { 
        id = this.id;
        $('#info').empty();
        img.each(function(i,elem) {
            var thisid = parseFloat(this.id);
            if (thisid <= id) {
                $(this).attr("src","http://test.epic-mine.ru/1.png");
            }
            else{
                $(this).attr("src","http://test.epic-mine.ru/3.png");
            }  
        }); 
        $('#info').append(id);
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вашу функцию практически не менял.
Убрал из нее вывод информации о количестве выбранных блоков и перенес расчет в другое место.

**[Решение](http://jsfiddle.net/oac2Lw13/3/)**:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    img = $("#heart img");
    // По умолчанию выбрано 0 блоков
    var current_hearts = 0;
    img.mouseenter(function (e) { 
        id = this.id;
        img.each(function(i,elem) {
            var thisid = parseFloat(this.id);
            if (thisid <= id) {
                $(this).attr("src","http://test.epic-mine.ru/1.png");
            }
            else{
                $(this).attr("src","http://test.epic-mine.ru/3.png");
            }  
        });
    });

    // Вся магия здесь. Количество блоков и их ширина не важны.
    img.mousemove(function(e){
        // Получаем смещение текущего блока относительно левого верхнего угла док-та
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        // Рассчитываем положение курсора мыши внутри этого блока
        // e.pageX - текущее положение курсора от левого края документа
        // offset.left - положение блока от левого края документа
        // Итого: relativeX - положение курсора от левого края текущего блока
        var relativeX = (e.pageX - offset.left);
        // Если указатель мыши во второй половине блока - +1. Иначе +0.5.
        var heart_state = (relativeX > ($(this).width() / 2)) ? 1 : 0.5);
        current_hearts = img.index($(this)) + heart_state;
        $('#info').text(current_hearts);
    });
});
```

Comment: @VenZell, Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 4):

Хоть решение уже нашлось, я всё равно хотел бы показать, как это можно сделать без картинок и кода поменьше. Кому-то да пригодится. [Смотрим пример](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/0bvtz40u/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="circle">
    <span class="semicircle half-left"></span>
    <span class="semicircle half-right"></span>
</div>
<div class="circle">
    <span class="semicircle half-left"></span>
    <span class="semicircle half-right"></span>
</div>
<div class="circle">
    <span class="semicircle half-left"></span>
    <span class="semicircle half-right"></span>
</div>
<div class="circle">
    <span class="semicircle half-left"></span>
    <span class="semicircle half-right"></span>
</div>
<div class="circle">
    <span class="semicircle half-left"></span>
    <span class="semicircle half-right"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.circle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    letter-spacing: -.36em;
}
.semicircle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #999;
}
.half-left {
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}
.half-right {
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}
.semicircle.picked {
    background-color: #060;
}
```

**JS**

```
var circle = $('.circle'), 
    semicircle = $('span', circle),
    cIndx = 0;
semicircle.on('mouseenter', function(){
    cIndx = $(this).index('.semicircle') + 1;
    semicircle.removeClass('picked').slice(0, cIndx).addClass('picked');
});
```

Comment: @Deonis, + за то что не поленились собрать полноценный пример с оформленным заполнением.